# Let f be entire function such that for some $n \geq 1$, $f^{(n)}(\frac {1}{k}) = 0 \forall k=1,2,3 ...$. Show that f is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

For a function $f:C\to C$ and $n \geq 1$, let $f^{(n)}$ denote the nth derivative of f and $f^{0}=f$. Let f be entire function such that for some $n \geq 1$, $f^{(n)}(\frac {1}{k}) = 0 \forall k=1,2,3 ...$. Show that f is polynomial

Can you tell me is this following correct?
Given $\forall n \geq N$, we have $f^{(n)}(\frac {1}{k}) = 0$

As $f^{(n)}$  exists as $f$is analytic through out. So $f^{(n)}$ is continuous at z=0, So $f^{(n)}(0)=0 \forall n \geq N$.

$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n \implies f(z) = a_0+a_1z+....a_Nz^N$ --> polynomial of degree N

Pls correct me if am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is not correct. The hypothesis only says 'for some $n$' and you are assuming that the hypothesis is 'for all $n \geq N$. Where did $N$ come form? Here is the correct proof: $f^{(n)}$ has zeros at the points $1,1/2,1/3,....$ so its zeros have have a limit point. Of course, $f^{(n)}$ is analytic. Hence $f^{(n)}\equiv 0$. Now you can use your power series argument to conclude that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: Sir i recently started complex analysis. Kindly explain here
1. $f^{(n)}$ is entire so it must contain only poles and removable singlualaries in finite complex plane. So $f^{(n)}(z) = 0 \forall z$
        (2). how can we say that for higher orders of n, $f^{(n)}$ = 0. We just proved at only some n          (3)f is entire, does it mean all higher orders  $f^{(n)}$ are also entire?

Comment: Yes. Entire functions have derivatives of all orders and all the derivatives  are also entire.

Comment: Sir thank you...I am refering to krishna series complex analysis(vashista). Such arguments i google them and read. But it is not present. Can you suggest me good book but simple to undertand?